# Redirect a domain name to another domain specific url

Tags: redirect, domain-name, dns-zone

Hello guys i am having the domain `www.myawesomedomain.com`

which i would like to redirect to `www.myotherdomain.co.uk/modules-plugins/`

I have tried this record:

```
* WebForward REDIRECT www.myotherdomain.co.uk/modules-plugins/
```

But it does not seem to work.

Is this possible via DNS Record? If yes how?

Is this possible via URLRewriteFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an index.html file in your old domain's root folder with the following content :

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.myotherdomain.co.uk/modules-plugins/">
```

Comment: This is tecnique was *deprecated* back in 2000: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element .

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible via DNS Record? If yes how?

No, this is not possible via DNS record.

> Is this possible via URLRewriteFilter?

You did not state which web server you are using, anyway yes, your web server is the right place to look for. You will want to issue a [HTTP 301 status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) to permanently redirect all clients from the first URL to the other.

Comment: I am using Apache tomcat and i can setup a rule for this. But my question is just like this i can redirect 1 domain to another? By this logic i can also redirect other domains that i do not possess to my domain

Comment: It seems you need to check what DNS is and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the service [redirect.name](http://redirect.name).
Just set a CNAME record and a TXT record. Without a third party service it is not possible with DNS only.

DNS Settings:

```
 www           IN  CNAME  alias.redirect.name
_redirect.www  IN  TXT    "Redirects to www.myotherdomain.co.uk/modules-plugins/"
```

If you use a 3rd party service be aware of the information disclosure to this service.

Comment: i do not understand the CNAME record exactly. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You basically set your CNAME record to redirect to a 3rd party site (alias.redirect.name in this case). This 3rd party site then evaluates the TXT record and redirects you to the given URL.

Comment: It may or may not be a concern that while functional, this technique discloses a lot of information about the website visitors to the third party service.

Comment: That is right that would be a negative point about it. I will make it more clear.